# Export[] performance

Tags: export, performance-tuning, bugs, system-performance

Consider this sequence of commands:

```
foo10 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 10}];
Export["D:\\Dropper\\Dropbox\\footest.csv", foo10] // AbsoluteTiming
{0.898086, "D:\\Dropper\\Dropbox\\footest.csv"}

foo100 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 100}];
Export["D:\\Dropper\\Dropbox\\footest.csv", foo100] // AbsoluteTiming
{7.428425, "D:\\Dropper\\Dropbox\\footest.csv"}

foo1000 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 1000}];
Export["D:\\Dropper\\Dropbox\\footest.csv", foo1000] // AbsoluteTiming
{65.063763, "D:\\Dropper\\Dropbox\\footest.csv"}
```

Two (at least) things leap to mind:

The first is that the performance is truly atrocious (this is on a very fast machine, on a local file system.

The second is that the times grow sublinearly in the size of the input, which indicates a whole'nother kind of weirdness.

Does anyone understand what is going on, and if there is a reasonable workaround?

**EDIT** Following up on @belisarius' suggestion, here are the Timing[] results for the three commands:

0.671875 4.65250 47.968750

From which we see that both the OS interaction and the internal computation are ridiculously slow. But it gets worse. In the middle of doing this experiment, when I was running the commands exactly as above with `AbsoluteTiming[]` replaced by `Timing[]`, between the first and the second command Mathematica informed me that it could not do the `Export[]` because the "footest.csv" file was already open (which means that it did not do the necessary `fclose()`, or whatever Windows calls it, of course changing the file name fixed it.

For posterity, this is Mathematica 10.0.1 on Windows 8.1

**ANOTHER EDIT** Just for completeness: I tried the same experiment with ".dat" instead of ".csv", and the results were essentially identical (including the `fclose()` bug). Which makes it surprising (though gratifying) that there is an actual format that works quickly, as pointed out by @Jens.

Comment: Can you count the I/O operations performed?

Comment: @belisarius I would love to hear a suggestion about how to count them...

Comment: You'll need some Operating System monitoring tool running in parallel

Comment: Perhaps you could also get some insight about the time spent on I/O by comparing the `Timing[]` and `AbsoluteTiming[]` evolutions

Comment: @Belisarius I added the `Timing[]` experiment, which resulted in an extra bonus.

Comment: Well, you nailed it. Somebody should get fired from a well known company :)

Comment: @belisarius Unfortunately, there is evidence that at least the performance problem (don't know about the fclose()) has been around for years. Since csv is a somewhat popular format for numerical data, I am at a loss as to why this is not a priority for the well-known company in question.

Comment: These are the kind of issues that always prevent me for suggesting Mma as an enterprise production environment. Probably there is a solution using some mixed-language environment, but you never know where the devil's tail can flog you again. It's a very nice prototyping and R&D platform, though.

Comment: @Belisarius I totally agree, though I would say that the fact that Mathematica's programming language is not formally specified in any sense (the implementation is the spec) is quite frightening, which is why I tend to avoid using the fancier syntactic feature (if not too many people use them, can I be really sure they are implemented correctly?) I see that Mr Wizard and you are braver men than I...

Comment: Try to export large DXF files (with circles) for another atrocious experience. Or animations in general...

Comment: I believe the bottleneck is not i/o but in the string conversion . Note `ExportString` and even `Map[ToString,exp,{2}]` give similar timing.

Comment: @george2079 You might be right that this takes more of the time, but notice that the system time for dumping out a 50Meg file is 20 seconds, which is really ridiculous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The speed issue is similar on Mac OS X. I can only speculate what's going on, so I better not even start.

But let me suggest a work-around. Since CSV is not in any way optimized for exporting numerical data, I would instead suggest to use a different format that has similar flexibility but is particularly designed for numerical data.

Of course, this is a workaround **only if** your intention is to save numerical data for later use by an application that's also able to read the alternate format. Here is what I tried, and it's *very* fast by comparison:

```
foo1000 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 1000}];

Export["footest.h5", foo1000] // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.521861, "footest.h5"} *)

foo = Import["footest.h5", "Data"]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.145216, Null} *)

foo[[1]] == foo1000

(* ==> True *)
```

The format I used is [`HDF5`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HDF5.html).

If you're able to work with packed arrays, then things get even faster:

```
foo1000 = 
  Developer`ToPackedArray@RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5000, 1000}];

Export["footest.h5", foo1000] // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.358825, "footest.h5"} *)

foo = Import["footest.h5", "Data"]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.084686, Null} *)

foo[[1]] == foo1000

(* ==> True *)
```

Comment: This is very helpful (and certainly is the kind of workaround I was looking for)!

Answer (score 3):

This may be a bit of a digression, but a raw binary write is faster still than 'hd5':
( On Windows w/ v.9.01 )

```
 x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2560, 2560}];
 ByteCount[x]/1024^2 // N                  (* 50.0001 *)
 Export["test.csv", x] // AbsoluteTiming  (*  120.05  *)
 Export["test.h5", x] // AbsoluteTiming   (*  1.965550  *)
 (f = OpenWrite["test.dat", BinaryFormat -> True];
      BinaryWrite[f, Flatten@x, "Real64"];
      Close[f];) // AbsoluteTiming        (*  0.452388 *)
```

Obviously issues with other application reading the file may dwarf the timing difference.
(I use the raw BinaryWrite to exchange data with C++ all the time )

hmm.. you can write a csv like this is near 10x faster than `Export`

```
 (f = OpenWrite["test2.csv", BinaryFormat -> True];
    BinaryWrite[f, 
    StringJoin[Riffle[StringJoin[Riffle[#, ","]] & /@ 
             Map[ToString[#, CForm] &, x, {2}], "\r\n"]]];  (*note windows line end
                                                             used here*)
   Close[f]) // AbsoluteTiming   (* 23.337002 *)
```

makes you wonder what `Export` is doing...

```
 Import["test.csv"] == Import["test2.csv"]
```

> True

Comment: On my Mac, with Mathematica version 8, the `h5` export is still faster than the `BinaryWrite`: the result were: `{0.575183,test.h5}`, and `{0.588023,Null}` respectively.

Comment: Could be a windows issue then.

Comment: Actually, it's not a Windows issue. On my Windows 8.1 machine the timings are : `{0.275268, test.h5}` vs `{0.344335, Null}`. **v10.0.1**

Comment: On my Vista 32bit, with v9.0.1, the timings are: `{2.566000, "test.h5"}` vs `{3.374000, Null}`…