# Comma issue from number point in csv export!

Tags: export, csv-format

Here is my issue:

I want to export to csv file some data:

```
Export["C:\\Documents and Settings\\commatest.csv", \
datafile, "Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> ";", "NumberPoint" -> ","}]
```

The output is something like this (When i open it with notepad):

**0;0;0;-0.013497386587717805;0.0019942835592972347**

I want the **NumberPoint** to be "," instead of "." in order to have the output:

**0;0;0;-0,013497386587717805;0,0019942835592972347**

Comment: I'm irritated that this stone age problem still exists. Usual workaround was using `String[]` and `StringReplace[]`. Not good for big data, though.

Comment: try doing  `Numberform[datafile, "NumberPoint" -> ","]`

Comment: The NumberForm works inside mathematica, but when i export the result it gives inside excel:  

NumberForm[{{1.3 2.54 4 23 5.323  0.0024}  {23.4 23 1.54434  121.324}}  "NumberPoint" -> " ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a workaround..

```
 exportsemiseparated[fname_String, data_?MatrixQ] := Module[{f},
        (f = OpenWrite[fname, BinaryFormat -> True];
            BinaryWrite[f, StringJoin[Riffle[StringJoin[Riffle[#, ";"]] & /@
            Map[StringReplace[ToString[CForm[#]], "." -> ","] &,
                 data, {2}], "\r\n"]]];(*note windows line end used here*)
         Close[f])]
 exportsemiseparated["test.out", {{4.5, 5.6 10^30, 0.06}, {"string", 1,6}}]
 FilePrint["test.out"]
```

> [image]

derived from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60141/2079 where we show the performance is at least comparable to `Export`

another approach..

```
 Export["test.out",
      StringReplace[
        ExportString[data, "Table", {"FieldSeparators" -> ";"}], "." -> ","] ,
              "Text"]
```

Comment: I test it but when i tried to export the FilePrint["test.out"], it didn't work:

Export["path.csv",FilePrint["test.out"]

I get an empty csv file

Comment: you don't export `Fileprint`, `exportsemiseparated` writes the file, the `FilePrint` is there to show that it worked.

Comment: it writes it where exactly?
i don't see a csv created

Comment: I used '.out' for the extension in the example but you can make that whatever you like. It goes in the current directory shown by `Directory[]`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't group options with { }. Also, "NumberPoint" is not an option for `Export`, but only for `Import` (and that is documented).

```
datafile = {{0, 0, 0, -0.013497386587717805, 0.0019942835592972347}};

ExportString[
   Map[
     StringReplace[ToString[#], "." -> ","] &, 
     datafile, 
     {2}
   ], 
   "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"
]
```

> 0;0;0;-0,0134974;0,00199428

Replace `ExportString` with `Export` and a filename to write the result to file instead of in your notebook (as I did for demonstration purposes).

Comment: better do `ToString[CForm@#]` in case any numbers require scientific notation.

Comment: I did export it to Csv file, and it works, but the problem that it exports all my matrix to the first cell only. and i am having problem reading it after inside VBA code.
Is there any way to export each line string in a cell?

Comment: Are you sure you want ; as fieldseparator? That's not usually the case for CSV's (COMMA seprated values).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: when you use comma as the number-point character you actually have to use something else to seperate fields, and using semicolon is AFAIK the quasi-standard then. This is very common on computers set to German language settings as there a comma is the default for the number-point character...