# Any solution to transfer data between Python and Mathematica

Tags: import, matlab, python

I think *Mathematica* handles .mat file not very well, python is pretty good at this kind of jobs. In this site, there are plenty of question related to calling *Mathematica* from Python, or calling Python from *Mathematica*. The answers are only valid for very small data, I believe like hundreds of numbers. Currently, I am working with data a little larger than that, a typical size is about (40960, 256). Thus I want to ask whether there is a solution to transfer data from one to another? Or a better .mat file interface?

Following is a sample of what is inside the .mat file.

[image: matfile]

The data transfer between `R` and `python` can be done seamlessly. Check [`rpy2`](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.5/html/introduction.html) for more information. Maybe `RLink` can be used in this case.

### Update

Handling .mat file in *Mathematica* is not as fast as in Python. However, thanks for linked page suggested by @The Toad, this process is much better.

Following are some tests:

in Python:

```
%time matlab.whosmat('test.mat')
CPU times: user 152 ms, sys: 10.2 ms, total: 162 ms
Wall time: 164 ms
Out[153]: 
[('exp03', (20480, 2), 'double'),
 ('exp22', (22528, 2), 'double'),
 ('exp09', (22528, 2), 'double'),
 ('exp31', (22528, 2), 'double'),
 ...
```

in *Mathematica*:

```
In[166]:= Timing@Import["~/test.mat", {"MAT", "Labels"}]

Out[166]= {0.851815, {"exp03", "exp22", "exp09", "exp31", "exp30", 
  "exp33", "exp32", "exp35", "exp34", "exp19", "exp18", "exp17", 
  "exp16", "exp15", "exp14", "exp13", "exp12", "exp11", "exp10", 
  "exp37", "exp36", "exp02", "Data", "exp08", "exp23", "exp20", 
  "exp21", "exp26", "exp27", "exp24", "exp25", "exp01", "exp28", 
  "exp29", "exp04", "exp05", "exp06", "exp07"}}
```

in Python

```
%time data=matlab.loadmat('test.mat')
CPU times: user 199 ms, sys: 28.2 ms, total: 228 ms
Wall time: 236 ms
```

in *Mathematica*:

```
In[168]:= Timing@Import["~/test.mat", {"MAT", "LabeledData"}];

In[169]:= %[[1]]

Out[169]= 0.838842
```

For another file:

In Python:

```
%time data=matlab.loadmat('test2.mat')
CPU times: user 3.55 s, sys: 381 ms, total: 3.93 s
Wall time: 3.98 s
```

In *Mathematica*:

```
In[1]:= Timing@Import["~/test2.mat", {"MAT", "LabeledData"}];

In[2]:= First[%]

Out[2]= 12.558158
```

Comment: Perhaps related: [Export performance](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60065/245)

Comment: @Jens yes, a possible solution. However, I have export the data every time and import to another. Frequently export and import are very slow.

Comment: You can [import MAT files](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10582/5) in Mathematica. Have you tried that?

Comment: @TheToad Yes, the user experience is terrible. The imported results are very hard to manipulate, especially for a .mat file with a lot of variables stored in. Just want to see what is in `st = SessionTime[];
Print@Short[test];
SessionTime[] - st` takes 15 seconds.

Comment: @TheToad Maybe I should Import the file variable by variable.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you want, but it sounds like you could really benefit by using `HDF5` format as I suggest in the answer linked above. It would just be a replacement for what you're already doing with `MAT` files, it seems. And I have yet to see any file format that is faster to import and export than `HDF5`.

Comment: @TheToad Thanks for your link answer. The speed of MMA is not as fast, but at least is much better than what I get earlier. If you are interested in the performance of MMA, I add some timing results in the question.

Comment: @Jens I will check the performance of MMA with `HDF5`, since it is pretty easy to convert files from `.mat` to `HDF5`.

Comment: @Jens `HDF5` is impressive, I add some timing results in the question. Maybe I should convert all the data files to .h5.

Comment: @Jens do you think I should move the timing results to an answer?  `HDF5` seems a solution of the problem.

Comment: You could write your section about hdf5 as an answer?

Comment: you might want to try fits as well?

Comment: @chris never thought `FITS` as a format for data storage. I will check this option out.

Comment: @chris `FITS` seems most working with image data. Can you please clarify how to use it in storage groups of matrix data.

Comment: for best performance use no formatting at all.  Write out raw binary and read into mathematica with `ReadList`

Comment: @george2079 saving raw binary is quite risky, because these files will be read in other computers and softwares. I think it is better to store metadata with the data.

Answer (score 17):

As suggested by @Jens, `HDF5` can be fast imported and manipulated in *Mathematica*. The performance of importing `HDF5` is as efficient as `MAT` file in Python and you can read only a part of `HDF5` file into memory. From the question, *Mathematica* is about 3~4 times slower in reading `MAT` files. The speed of reading `HDF5` files are very close to the speed in `Python`.

### Performance of `HDF5`

As suggested by @Jens, performance of `HDF5` has been tested. I have to say performance of `HDF5` is impressive, the performance is close to .mat file in Python (Because .mat get more compression, the read speed is a little slower.). Since I do not know much about how to convert `.mat` file to `.mat` of version 7.3. I directly convert .mat to .hdf file. Following are some timing results:

For the first file:
    In[1]:= fname = "test.h5";
    dat = Timing@Import[fname]

```
Out[2]= {0.109260, {"/Data", "/__globals__", "/exp01", "/exp02", 
  "/exp03", "/exp04", "/exp05", "/exp06", "/exp07", "/exp08", 
  "/exp09", "/exp10", "/exp11", "/exp12", "/exp13", "/exp14", 
  "/exp15", "/exp16", "/exp17", "/exp18", "/exp19", "/exp20", 
  "/exp21", "/exp22", "/exp23", "/exp24", "/exp25", "/exp26", 
  "/exp27", "/exp28", "/exp29", "/exp30", "/exp31", "/exp32", 
  "/exp33", "/exp34", "/exp35", "/exp36", "/exp37"}}

In[3]:= dat = Timing@Import[fname, "Data"];
First[dat]

Out[4]= 0.142046

In[5]:= dat = Timing@Import[fname, {"Datasets", "Data"}];

In[6]:= dat[[1]]

Out[6]= 0.036610

In[7]:= Dimensions@dat[[2]]

Out[7]= {20480, 37}
```

For the second file:

```
In[1]:= fname = "test2.h5";
dat = Timing@Import[fname]

Out[2]= {0.111127, {"/Data", "/Spec", "/__globals__", "/exp001", 
  "/exp002", "/exp003", "/exp004", "/exp005", "/exp006", "/exp007", 
  "/exp008", "/exp009", "/exp010", "/exp011", "/exp012", "/exp013", 
  "/exp014", "/exp015", "/exp016", "/exp017", "/exp018", "/exp...}}

In[3]:= dat = Timing@Import[fname, "Data"];
First[dat]

Out[4]= 2.565427

In[5]:= dat = Timing@Import[fname, {"Datasets", "Data"}];

In[6]:= dat[[1]]

Out[6]= 0.143031

In[7]:= Dimensions@dat[[2]]

Out[7]= {40960, 246}
```

### Convention of `MAT` file to `HDF5`

The problem of the solution is how to convert `MAT` file to `HDF5` and the compatibility with new version Matlab is a plus.

Convention `MAT` file to `HDF5` can be done using `h5py` in Python. I would like to recommend [`hdf5storage`](https://github.com/frejanordsiek/hdf5storage), which is easy to use and have very similar options as `savemat` in `scipy`. The `HDF5` file can also be `load` in Matlab using `load` command.

```
import hdf5storage as h
from scipy.io import loadmat
data = loadmat('test.mat')
h.savemat('t.mat',data)
```

Currently, `hdf5storage` does not support compression. The issue is reported by the author herself last year. Here is a workaround before it is implemented. Changing the default option in `__init__.py` L192-L196 will always compress the file.

```
    # Set the h5py options to use for writing scalars and arrays to
    # blank for now.

    self.scalar_options = dict()
    self.array_options = {'compression':'gzip'}
```

I will contact the author to fix this issue ASAP.

Comment: Good to see that it worked for you.

Comment: @Jens Yes, thanks a lot for your suggestion! With `hdf5storage`, I can simply convert my old files to `MAT` version 7.3.